# White div background displays as grey

Tags: css, styling

I have a content div displaying an image and a header positioned on/at the top of the content div. The original background for the header (which contains some text) is black with some opacity, when the user hovers over the image/header the background color and text color of the header div change to white/black. However I've found that setting the background to white results in an off gray color instead (regardless of opacity). What should I use to get opacity to work with a white background? Attached is the CSS for what I'm doing. #textWrap (header w/ text) is inside of #gameDisplayBugSmash (an image).

```
#gameDisplayBugSmash {
   height: auto;
   width: 50%;
   position: relative;
}

#gameDisplayBugSmash:hover #textWrap {
   background-color: white;
   color: #000;
}

#textWrap {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #FFF;
}


<div id = "contentSaver">
<div id = "contentGames"> 
<div id = "gameDisplayBugSmash">
<a href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()"         onmouseover="MM_swapImage('bugSmash','','images/bugSmashFaded.png',1)"><img src="images/PortII_DesignMocks-Recovered_0002s_0005_Layer-17-copy-3.png" width="100%" height="auto" id="bugSmash" /></a>
<div id = "textWrap">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div id = "bugSmashTitle">Bug Smash</div>
    </td>
    <td>
    <div id = "bugSmashTextD">A final project for one of my coding classes. This was my introduction to using monogame for  development.</div>
   </tr>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What happens if you change the background-color on #textWrap to something completely different, like red? The rgba(0,0,0,0.6) will show 60% black, which on a white background will display grey.

Comment: How about some HTML, we can analyze what we see, it's better than speculating on what we can't see.